# Bouncy Castle NTRU encryption export public key

Tags: java, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I got   AsymmetricKeyParameter a = asymmetricCipherKeyPair.getPublic();
I've spent couple of hours on this one and do not know how to turn the public key into a sequence of bytes.  any ideas?

```
 NTRUEncryptionKeyPairGenerator ntruEncryptionKeyPairGenerator = new NTRUEncryptionKeyPairGenerator();
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters ntruEncryptionKeyPairGeneratorParameters = NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.EES1087EP2;


        ntruEncryptionKeyPairGenerator.init(ntruEncryptionKeyPairGeneratorParameters);


        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair asymmetricCipherKeyPair = ntruEncryptionKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

I tried

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter a = asymmetricCipherKeyPair.getPublic();
SubjectPublicKeyInfo info = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.createSubjectPublicKeyInfo(a);
```

but it throws"key parameters not recognised."

Answer (score 1):

```
((NTRUEncryptionPublicKeyParameters)asymmetricCipherKeyPair.getPublic()).getEncoded();
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.